# Crossdomain error with phonegap/cordova

Tags: ajax, .htaccess, cordova, cross-domain, wp-api

I'm using Phonegap / Cordova to try a connection in the WP-API of wordpress.

"The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

My ajax:

```
jQuery.ajax ({
    url: 'linktoserver.com/wp-json/wp/v2/publication?_embed',
    method: 'GET',
    crossDomain: true,
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {

    },
    success: function (result) {
        renderMap (result)
    }
});
```

My .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</ IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase / server /
RewriteRule ^ index \ .php $ - [L]
RewriteCond% {REQUEST_FILENAME}! -f
RewriteCond% {REQUEST_FILENAME}! -d
RewriteRule. /server/index.php [L]
</ IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I tested all browsers using a simulator, using my own cell phone for testing and in all cases the error continues.

EDIT 1:

My config.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.e4g.app" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>MyApp</name>
    <description>
         MyApp.
    </description>
    <author email="juliano.t@hotmail.com" href="juliano.t@hotmail.com">
        MyApp Team
    </author>
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <preference name="Orientation" value="portrait" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverScroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="BackgroundColor" value="#1FB5FCFF" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="60" src="res/icons/ios/icon-60.png" width="60" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="120" src="res/icons/ios/icon-60-2x.png" width="120" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="180" src="res/icons/ios/icon-60-3x.png" width="180" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="76" src="res/icons/ios/icon-76.png" width="76" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="152" src="res/icons/ios/icon-76-2x.png" width="152" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="40" src="res/icons/ios/icon-40.png" width="40" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="80" src="res/icons/ios/icon-40-2x.png" width="80" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="57" src="res/icons/ios/icon-57.png" width="57" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="114" src="res/icons/ios/icon-57-2x.png" width="114" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="72" src="res/icons/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="144" src="res/icons/ios/icon-72-2x.png" width="144" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="29" src="res/icons/ios/icon-small.png" width="29" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="58" src="res/icons/ios/icon-small-2x.png" width="58" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="50" src="res/icons/ios/icon-50.png" width="50" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="100" src="res/icons/ios/icon-50-2x.png" width="100" />
    <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="ldpi" src="res/icons/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="mdpi" src="res/icons/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="hdpi" src="res/icons/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xhdpi" src="res/icons/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xxhdpi" src="res/icons/android/icon-144-xxhdpi.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xxxhdpi" src="res/icons/android/icon-192-xxxhdpi.png" />
    <splash src="splash.png" />
    <splash gap:platform="ios" height="480" src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png" width="320" />
    <splash gap:platform="ios" height="960" src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" width="640" />
    <splash gap:platform="ios" height="1024" src="res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png" width="768" />
    <splash gap:platform="ios" height="2048" src="res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-portrait-2x.png" width="1536" />
    <splash gap:platform="ios" height="768" src="res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png" width="1024" />
    <splash gap:platform="ios" height="1536" src="res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-landscape-2x.png" width="2048" />
    <splash gap:platform="ios" height="1136" src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-568h-2x.png" width="640" />
    <splash gap:platform="ios" height="1334" src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-667h.png" width="750" />
    <splash gap:platform="ios" height="2208" src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-736h.png" width="1242" />
    <splash gap:platform="ios" height="1242" src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
    <splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="land-hdpi" src="res/screens/android/screen-hdpi-landscape.png" />
    <splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="land-ldpi" src="res/screens/android/screen-ldpi-landscape.png" />
    <splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="land-mdpi" src="res/screens/android/screen-mdpi-landscape.png" />
    <splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="land-xhdpi" src="res/screens/android/screen-xhdpi-landscape.png" />
    <splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-hdpi" src="res/screens/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" />
    <splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-ldpi" src="res/screens/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" />
    <splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-mdpi" src="res/screens/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" />
    <splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-xhdpi" src="res/screens/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" />
    <engine name="ios" spec="^4.4.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="^2.4.1">
        <variable name="CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value=" " />
        <variable name="PHOTOLIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value=" " />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-transport-security" spec="^0.1.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.2" />
</widget>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a protocol to the ajax url (`http://` or `https://`), if you don't provide one, then `file://` will be used as Cordova/Phonegap apps load the app code from www folder using that protocol

Comment: then it might be a whitelist configuration issue, provide your config.xml